# Imprimindo listas de forma tabular com geradores

Tags: python, lista, iterator

Tenho uma lista que representa 5 períodos de um mês com 31 dias, e cada período contém valores de meta diária para um vendedor do varejo. Apenas para fins de elucidação a estrutura vazia seria assim:

```
[[], [], [], [], []]
```

**ITERANDO SOBRE A LISTA (COM VALORES):**

```
for periodo in plan:
    print(periodo)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0]
[2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0]
[2000.0, 2000.0, 1250.0, 1250.0, 1250.0, 1250.0, 1250.0]
[1250.0, 1250.0, 1250.0, 1250.0, 1250.0, 1250.0, 1250.0]
[1250.0, 1250.0, 1250.0]
```

Os períodos não ficaram iguais pois há um corte nos domingos.

Quero plotar esses valores de forma modular, com um cabeçalho horizontal que discrimina cada período assim:

```
print(f'\033[34m{"1º PERÍODO":<15}{"2º PERÍODO":<15}{"3º PERÍODO":<15}{"4º PERÍODO":<15}{"5º PERÍODO":<15}\033[m')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1º PERÍODO     2º PERÍODO     3º PERÍODO     4º PERÍODO     5º PERÍODO
```

Minha dificuldade é fazer com que cada elemento da lista planejamento (períodos) estejam organizados de forma horizontal de acordo com o cabeçalho. Tentei uma solução com `geradores`, entre outras, mas simplesmente não funciona.

**Minha primeira tentativa com geradores foi esta:**

```
gerador_periodo = (periodo for periodo in plan)
print(f"{next(gerador_periodo)}, {next(gerador_periodo)}, {next(gerador_periodo)}, {next(gerador_periodo)}, {next(gerador_periodo)}")
```

Obviamente, falhou, pois ele imprimi os períodos de forma linear, não respeitando a organização do cabeçalho acima.

**Minha segunda tentativa foi usando uma `list comprehension` com loop `for` para imprimir quebrando linhas:**

```
print(f"{[print(num) for num in next(gerador_periodo)]}, {[print(num) for num in next(gerador_periodo)]}, ...")
```

Aqui, recebi na tela todos os valores um abaixo do outro seguidos pelos 5 períodos com valores `None`(Porquê?). Tentei usar o parâmetro `end` de diversas formas também.

É possível construir essa estrutura sem usar Pandas, DataFrame, etc?
Alguma outra idéia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua segunda tentativa gerou vários `None` porque a *list comprehension* está usando o retorno de `print(num)`, e [`print` sempre retorna `None`](https://ideone.com/BPsdlr).

De qualquer forma, pelo que entendi, você quer que na primeira linha tenha o primeiro elemento de cada um dos períodos, na segunda linha, o segundo elemento de cada um dos períodos, etc.

Ou seja, no fundo você quer percorrer todas as listas ao mesmo tempo. Geralmente usa-se [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) para isso, mas `zip` interrompe o *loop* quando a menor das listas termina. Só que nesse caso você quer ir até o final da maior das listas, então deve-se usar [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
plan = [
    [2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0],
    [2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0],
    [2000.0, 2000.0, 1250.0, 1250.0, 1250.0, 1250.0, 1250.0],
    [1250.0, 1250.0, 1250.0, 1250.0, 1250.0, 1250.0, 1250.0],
    [1250.0, 1250.0, 1250.0]
]

from itertools import zip_longest

size = 15
print(f'{"1º PERÍODO":<{size}}{"2º PERÍODO":<{size}}{"3º PERÍODO":<{size}}{"4º PERÍODO":<{size}}{"5º PERÍODO":<{size}}')

for metas in zip_longest(*plan, fillvalue=''):
    print(('{:<{size}}' * len(metas)).format(*metas, size=size))
```

O asterisco em `*plan` e `*metas` serve para fazer o [*unpacking*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). Ou seja, `zip_longest(*plan)` é o mesmo que fazer `zip_longest(plan[0], plan[1], etc...)`. Mas assim eu não preciso saber a quantidade exata de elementos em `plan`.

A cada iteração, a variável `metas` será uma tupla contendo os elementos de cada uma das listas contidas em `plan`. Na primeira iteração, ela tem o primeiro elemento de cada uma, na segunda iteração, o segundo elemento e por aí vai.

O `fillvalue` indica o valor a ser usado quando uma lista for menor que as outras e não tiver mais elementos a serem iterados. No caso, usei a string vazia, mas você pode colocar o que quiser ali.

Para formatar, gerei uma string que tem várias vezes `{:<{size}}` (a quantidade de vezes é o número de elementos em `metas`, ou seja, todos os valores dela serão formatados igualmente). Em seguida eu passo os valores, também usando *unpacking*, e indico o tamanho a ser usado no alinhamento.

A saída é:

```
1º PERÍODO     2º PERÍODO     3º PERÍODO     4º PERÍODO     5º PERÍODO     
2000.0         2000.0         2000.0         1250.0         1250.0         
2000.0         2000.0         2000.0         1250.0         1250.0         
2000.0         2000.0         1250.0         1250.0         1250.0         
2000.0         2000.0         1250.0         1250.0                        
2000.0         2000.0         1250.0         1250.0                        
2000.0         2000.0         1250.0         1250.0                        
               2000.0         1250.0         1250.0
```

---

Outro exemplo, mudando o `fillvalue`:

```
for metas in zip_longest(*plan, fillvalue='-'):
    print(('{:<{size}}' * len(metas)).format(*metas, size=size))
```

Saída:

```
1º PERÍODO     2º PERÍODO     3º PERÍODO     4º PERÍODO     5º PERÍODO     
2000.0         2000.0         2000.0         1250.0         1250.0         
2000.0         2000.0         2000.0         1250.0         1250.0         
2000.0         2000.0         1250.0         1250.0         1250.0         
2000.0         2000.0         1250.0         1250.0         -              
2000.0         2000.0         1250.0         1250.0         -              
2000.0         2000.0         1250.0         1250.0         -              
-              2000.0         1250.0         1250.0         -
```

---

Obs: para o cabeçalho, você também pode usar:

```
print(('{:<{size}}' * len(plan)).format(*map(lambda x: f'{x + 1}º PERÍODO', range(len(plan))), size=size))
```

Ou:

```
print(*map(lambda x: f'{str(x + 1) + "º PERÍODO":<{size}}', range(len(plan))), sep='')
```

Assim ele também fica dinâmico, de acordo com a quantidade de elementos em `plan`.

Comment: @hksotsubo, ajudou muito! O size tendo que ser atribuído a size é por causa da interpolação dentro de outra interpolação, né?

Comment: Uma outra coisa interessante foi que não consegui formatar a string com 2 casas flutuantes (no caso de precisar). Tive que fazer esta alteração direto na outra função que fornece o planejamento para esta função modeladora que você criou comigo.

Comment: @dev.curi O `size` é porque dentro da string usada no `format`, ele tem que saber o que colocar ali (detalhe que não precisaria ter o mesmo nome, diferente de uma f-string, que tem que ser o mesmo nome da variável). Pra deixar sempre 2 casas decimais, bastaria usar `{:<{size}.2f}`. Mas como nesse caso tem strings vazias entre os valores, vai dar erro pq esse formato sempre espera números. Então uma solução seria formatar fora do `print`. Exemplo: https://ideone.com/Ud3LTW

Comment: Perfeito. Como eu falei, plan é uma lista gerada por uma outra função chamada planejador que vai dando append em valores num loop for. Eu dei append numa f-string formatada com .2f pra já receber os valores dessa forma na função de tabular. O problema foi na hora de calcular a soma dos períodos pra colocar abaixo de cada coluna pra deixar ainda mais completinho. Fiz uma conversão para float in-place e calculei a soma de cada período com sum().

Comment: Tenho 5 meses de Python e o desafio é sempre entender qual é o melhor caminho, o mais pythonico. Aos poucos isso vai ficando mais claro. Na sua opinião, o caminho que defini é um bom caminho?

Comment: Quando vc diz que o format sempre espera números vc quer dizer o quê? Size no caso é um inteiro. Tem que ser um número mesmo?!

Comment: @dev.curi Sim, o size ali é a quantidade de espaços que vão ser usados, então só faz sentido se for um número inteiro. Veja isso - e muito mais opções - na documentação: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec - mas o que eu quis dizer é que o formato `.2f` só funciona com números (pois se não for número não vai ter casas decimais e esse formato diz pra imprimir só 2 casas), mas como também tem a string vazia em alguns casos (nas colunas que ficam vazias), então ele não serve, por isso eu fiz a formatação em uma função separada